# Visual Basic Database and registration form

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2012, vba

This is my first time doing VB. I have successfully created the login form, but I am having issues with the User Registration. The moment I  click register, it gives me error that Database connection Failed and cannot INSERT INTO Registration. Please help. 
Thanks in advance

```
If rtxtpassword.Text = "" Or rtxtusername.Text = "" Or rtxtfname.Text = "" Or rtxtlname.Text = "" Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please complete the required fields..", "Authentication Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
        End If

        ' Connect to DB
        Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\logan_000\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Point Of Sale Application\Point Of Sale Application\database.accdb"

        Try
            'Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Registration WHERE username='" & rtxtusername.Text & "' AND Password = '" & rtxtpassword.Text & rtxtfname.Text & "' AND Fname = '" & rtxtlname.Text & "' AND Lname =  '"
            Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Registration (username, Password, Fname, Lname) VALUES (" & rtxtusername.Text & ", " & rtxtpassword.Text & ", " & rtxtfname.Text & ", " & rtxtlname.Text & ")"
            'Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO Registration (username, Password, Fname, Lname) VALUES('" & rtxtusername.Text & "'," & "'" & rtxtpassword.Text & "',"
            Dim sqlCom As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql)

            'Open Database Connection
            sqlCom.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Dim sqlRead As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader()

            If sqlRead.Read() Then
                Form1.Show()
                'Me.Hide()
                Me.Close()
            Else
                ' If user enter wrong username and password combination
                ' Throw an error message
                MessageBox.Show("Registration Failed..", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

                'Clear all fields
                rtxtusername.Text = ""
                rtxtfname.Text = ""
                rtxtlname.Text = ""
                rtxtpassword.Text = ""

                'Focus on Username field
                rtxtusername.Focus()
            End If
            'Connection failure Dialog box
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database.. System Error Message:  " & ex.Message, "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: a) dont store passwords as plain text, b) use SQL parameters instead of gluing bits of string together  c) dont use a reader to INSERT use ExecuteNonQuery d) Connections and Object should be disposed of e) VB.NET is not vba or access-vba

Comment: @Plutonix Thanks for your advice, is it possible to post a sample code, it will help me understand, because I am new in this field

Comment: The answer to the question you didnt ask has some [sample code here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)...the other things were just being helpful...except for parameters, that's pretty important on several levels